# Strip entire html link (including text) with PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have a collection of text that I am trying to process with PHP dynamically (the data comes from an XML file), however I want to strip the a link and the text that is linked.

PHP's strip_tags takes out the `<a etc...>` and `</a>` but not the text **in between**.

I am currently trying to use the Regex `preg_replace('#(<a.*?>).*?(</a>)#', '', $content);`

Another thing to note is the links have styles, classes, href and titles.

Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Comment: For reference, you've grouped the anchor tags but not the content, which is where the problem lies. preg_replace replaces the grouped element (those included in parenthesis). You can try the following though: `#(<a[^>]*?>.*?</a>)#i` (i flag for a case insensitive compare)

Comment: briefly tested shorter regex version, just for fun :) `preg_replace ('/<(?:a|\/)[^>]*>/', '', $data);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the solution(s) posted as comments, they seemed to work best and were exactly what I was looking for!

"For reference, you've grouped the anchor tags but not the content, which is where the problem lies. preg_replace replaces the grouped element (those included in parenthesis). You can try the following though: `#(<a[^>]*?>.*?</a>)#i` (i flag for a case insensitive compare)" – Brad Christie

"briefly tested shorter regex version, just for fun :) `preg_replace ('/<(?:a|\/)[^>]*>/', '', $data);`" – Cyber-Guard Design yesterday

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
$content=preg_replace('/<a[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/iU','',$content);
```

Comment: Awesome! Now I see the reason for learning regular expressions well! And how do I strip tags but not the ones with "<img" in them?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), for example (untested!):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile('foo.php');
$domNodeList = $doc->getElementsByTagname('a'); 
$len = count($domNodeList);
for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
    $domNodeList[$i]->parentNode->removeChild($domNodeList[$i]);
}
$doc->saveHTMLFile('output.html');
```

Or using [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm):

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com/');
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) { 
   $element->outertext = '';
}
$html->save('output.html');
```

Comment: @Cyber-Guard Design - I don't think it is overly complicated. And it will certainly be more reliable than a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Because the *a*-Element is not the online one, that can break your page, you better should use a whitelist approach, like [strip_tags()](http://php.net/strip-tags).

Comment: Sorry really have no idea what you mean...?

Comment: I dont know exactly, what you want, but usually you should specify, which tags are allowed, and not, which are not allowed. If you want to remove the tags because of security issues, think of _iframe_, _img_, or _link_.

Answer (score -1):

With regex, but not thoroughly tested

```
echo preg_replace('#(<a.*?>)(.*?)(<\/a>)#','$2', $str);
```

Also, the `limit` argument set to -1 will set it to no limit.